# Duplicate mongodb element in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, duplicates

I need duplicate a element of a mongodb array but I have no idea how to do this...

I tried to use the "set" with positional "$ []", but it was not possible to access the value of "field1", I was only able to create the second field with a fixed value.

Regards.

```
// My actual document
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd70f5678d408f3f1c4228a"),
    "docId" : "1234567890" ,
    "history" : [
        {
            "field1" : "value a"
        },
        {
            "field1" : "value b"
        },
        {
            "field1" : "value c"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
//My desired document
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd70f5678d408f3f1c4228a"),
    "docId" : "1234567890" ,
    "history" : [
        {
            "field1" : "value a",
            "field2" : "value a",
        },
        {
            "field1" : "value b",
            "field2" : "value b"
        },
        {
            "field1" : "value c",
            "field2" : "value c"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So if you wanted to update your existing doc, what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: will the fieldname `field2` be the same for all of this history elements?